Next JS app had jwt secret error when 2 applications running together
pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
            },
            authorize: async (credentials) => {
                const cmsLogin = async (
                    credentials: Record<"username" | "password", string> | undefined
                ) => {
                    const apiUrl = `${process.env.API_HOST_ACCESS}/UserAccess`;

                    const defaultHeaders = {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            Authorization:
                                "Basic " +
                                Buffer.from(`${process.env.API_USERNAME}:${process.env.API_PASSWORD}`, "binary")
                                    .toString("base64"),
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        const rawRes = await fetch(apiUrl, {
                            ...defaultHeaders,
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                sysuserId: credentials?.username,
                                sysuserPwd: credentials?.password
                            })
                        })
                        const response: CMSLoginResponse = await rawRes.json();
                        return { loginData: response }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log("next auth login error", error)
                    }
                }

                const user = await cmsLogin(credentials);
                console.log({ user })

                if (user && user.loginData.code === 0) {

                    return {
                        id: `${credentials?.username}`,
                        sysuserId: credentials?.username,
                        name: user.loginData.result.sysuserName,
                    }
                } else if (user?.loginData.code === 2) {
                    throw new Error(user.loginData.msg);
                    // } else {
                    //     throw new Error(user?.loginData.msg)
                } else if (user?.loginData.code === -2) {
                    throw new Error(user?.loginData.msg);
                } else if (user?.loginData.code) {
                    throw new Error(user?.loginData.msg);
                }
                return null;
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token, user }: { session: Session; token: JWT; user: User | AdapterUser }) {
            // session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            console.log('callback session', session);

            if (session.user) {
                session.user = {
                    ...session.user,
                    sysuserId: token.user.sysuserId,
                    // sysuserId: token.user.sysuserId,
                };
            }
            return session; // The return type will match the one returned in `useSession()`
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = user;
            }
            return token;
        },
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
            console.log('signin user', user);
            return user != null;
        },
    },
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
        updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
        generateSessionToken: () => {
            return randomUUID?.() ?? randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
        },
    },
    jwt: {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: basePath !== undefined && basePath !== '' ? `/${basePath}` : ``,
        error: '/',
        signOut: basePath !== undefined && basePath !== '' ? `/${basePath}` : ``
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET, <-- I already added in .env.local
};

package.json
    "next-auth": "^4.24.5",

Error: [next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed'

The error message appeared when I tried to run 2 Next JS applications at the same time and I checked clearly that the secret value, port number and base path are all in different names in 2 applications so I could not figure out where should be the error. May I ask what is the solution in order to fix the error run 2 applications at the same time correctly?
